# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'errors')

Tags: javascript

From few weeks i do have an issue with my contact formular (worked great for few years ), now it doesnt send e-mails anymore and

With DevTools from Chrome show me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'errors')
at Object.success (kontakt.min.js:1)
at i (jquery.3.2.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.3.2.1.min.js:2)
at A (jquery.3.2.1.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

then when i go to kontakt.min.js it show me the following line:

```
 $(".alert").delay(2e3).fadeOut("slow")) : $("#contact").fadeIn(1e3).append('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><div class="container"><div class="alert-icon"><i class="now-ui-icons objects_support-17"></i></div><strong>' + e.errors.errors + "</div></div>")
```

I cant figure it out by my self and I please ask you for a little help

Thank you!

Ill post my code:

```
$("#contact").validate({
//rules:
},
errorElement: "span",
errorClass: "help-block error-help-block warning-text",
errorPlacement: function(e, a) {
    a.parent(".input-group").length || "checkbox" === a.prop("type") || "radio" === a.prop("type") ? e.insertAfter(a.parent()) : e.insertAfter(a)
},
highlight: function(e) {
    $(e).closest(".input-group").removeClass("has-success").addClass("has-danger")
},
unhighlight: function(e) {
    $(e).closest(".input-group").removeClass("has-danger").addClass("has-success")
},
succes: function(e) {
    $(e).closest(".input-group").removeClass("has-danger").addClass("has-success")
},
submitHandler: function(e) {
    var a = {
        name: $("input[name=name]").val(),
        email: $("input[name=email]").val(),
        phone: $("input[name=phone]").val(),
        nachricht: $("textarea[name=nachricht]").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "assets/php/kfrm.inc.php",
        data: a,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(e) {
            e.success ? ($("#contact").fadeIn(1e3).append('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><div class="container"><div class="alert-icon"><i class="now-ui-icons ui-2_like"></i></div><strong>' + e.posted + "</div></div>"),
            $("#contact").each(function() {
                this.reset()
            }),
            $(".input-group").each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass("has-success")
            }),
            $(".alert").delay(2e3).fadeOut("slow")) : $("#contact").fadeIn(1e3).append('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><div class="container"><div class="alert-icon"><i class="now-ui-icons objects_support-17"></i></div><strong>' + e.errors.errors + "</div></div>")
        }
    })
}
```

});

and php

```
 $errors = array(); 
$form_data = array();
.......
$send = mail($emailTo, $subject, $Body, $headers);
if($send) {
    $form_data['success'] = true;
    $form_data['posted'] = 'My message';
            } else { 
                    $form_data['success'] = false;
                    $errors['errors'] = 'E-mail not send';  
                  }
```

I should mention that on online website i dont have any errors, anyway the form is not send, just apear the suuces message.

On another server I have a temporary adress , there I have this erros.
Diferent hosting providers.

Also I should mention that works just fine untill on my acctually hosting SSL Certificate expired, afther i renewed the SSL Certificate form doesnt wotk anymore

Comment: Then either `e` or `e.errors` is `undefined`.  Where do you define `e`?  When you debug, what does it contain?  What do you expect it to contain?  Why?

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)